# Regex: Is it possible to validate a port and a port-range with one regex?

Tags: regex, validation

I know that there are many questions in this area, however I haven't found one that could provide any help or answer to my problem, and as a complete regex-newb I need your help.

I'm using this regex to validate port numbers:

```
^([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$
```

But is it possible to create one regex that can both validate a single portnumber and a port range in the format `portStart:portEnd` ?

Examples:

Allowed:

```
6112
6112:6120
27015:28000
```

Not allowed:

```
6112:
:6113 
6112-7777
27100(any other character than colon)28000
```

Comment: The port numbers are, well..., numbers. Isn't it easier to split the string using `:` or `-` as separator, check that the result contains exactly one or two components then check that each component is a positive number no greater than 65535? All these in several lines of code (depending on the language you use) and without any (difficult to read and understand) regexp.

Comment: Well it wouldn't be a big problem to implement the functionality to do that, but I was just wondering if this was possible at all, as it would an optimal solution for my current task.

Comment: It depend what do you mean by "optimal". If you have to check for millions of strings then the regex solution is probably the one that runs fastest (for sure, if you use an interpreted language). Otherwise, aim for code readability. If the regex you posted works, let's use `X` to denote its inner part (without the start and end markers). The regex you want is something like `^X([:-]X)?$`. Remember you also need to check that the first port is smaller than the second one to have a valid range, and this is not possible using regex.

Comment: @axiac Alright, thank you for your answer. I seems that the best solution would be to split it then.

Comment: You mean the range is optional, right? It is easy with an optional group: `^([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5‌​])(?::([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]))?$`. Do not copy this regex from the comment, see [the pattern demo here](https://regex101.com/r/yU1jJ6/1).

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: In comments, you mention that by range validation you mean to check if the first range part is lower than the second. Surely, it is not possible with regex (only .NET regex can do that, but the pattern would be overkill), split with `:`, case both chunks to numbers and compare *numbers*.

If you want to just make sure a string is either one port or a range of ports *in any order*, you might try a regex with an optional group `(?:<PATTERN_BLOCK>)?`. **Use a regex only if you cannot use any dedicated programming language means**.

```
^([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])(?::([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]))?$
```

Breaking it into blocks:

```
^                        # Start of string
   (                     # Port number regex
     [0-9]{1,4}|
     [1-5][0-9]{4}|
     6[0-4][0-9]{3}|
     65[0-4][0-9]{2}|
     655[0-2][0-9]|
     6553[0-5]
   )
   (?:                  # Optional group start
       :                # The port range delimiter
       (                # Port number regex
         [0-9]{1,4}|
         [1-5][0-9]{4}|
         6[0-4][0-9]{3}|
         65[0-4][0-9]{2}|
         655[0-2][0-9]|
         6553[0-5]
       )
   )?                         # Optional group end
$                             # End of string
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iT8aC8/1)

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for! However as axiac mentioned I need to split it in order to make sure that `portStart < portEnd` so i made another solution where I can use my original regex on both values from the split.

Comment: Actually, there is no mention of checking if the first part of the range must be numerically lower than the second part. That can only be done with .NET regex in a very ugly way. With this regex, you can only make sure the parts are conforming the regex, and if you add capturing groups over the parts, you will be able to match them. Splitting the values and fruther casting them to numbers and comparing *numbers* is of course a way to go.

Comment: Note: this will match port `0` which may or may not (usually not) be a valid value for your application.